# Can I use Realm for all data storage, or should I use NSUserDefaults for storing username/password?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nsuserdefaults

I have an application which has a username/password login. Once logged in, the user should remain logged in until they log out, i.e. the user remains logged in even if they have no connection.

Currently I am authenticating the user, but I am unable to keep them logged in. Should I store the user details in NSUserDefaults for logging in on launch, or is there a way of keeping the user logged in using just Realm?

Thanks in advance!

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: userCredentials, server: (url! as URL)) { user, error in
    guard user != nil else {
        // Handles error
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
            syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user!, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://127.0.0.1:9080/~/realmtasks")!)
        )
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Update: Maybe the answer to my problem is Apple Keychain?

Comment: pls do provide code samples, but keep it focused on the problem.

Comment: Please always provide supporting code to allow people to understand your question better and provide helpful solution quicker.

Comment: use `NSCoding` and archive then save in `userDefaults`. But saving the password in `userDefaluts` is not considerable!

Comment: I think the bigger question here is: why can't you keep your users' sessions alive? Once authenticated, they should last indefinitely. As far as I know, Realm doesn't have an arbitrary session timeout. Which form of auth are you using to define `userCredentials`?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Yeah that's the behaviour I require, and I have defined userCredentials as:    SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: _, password: _, register: _)

Comment: So, are you using any keychain library for saving credentials? Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @AnuragSharma I haven't had a chance to implement it yet, but I believe so, thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store passwords or any sensitive information inside `NSUserDefault`,  by using a simple file manager you can read all the data stored in it, it is really unsafe. 
 you don't even need a database or sort of. The right place to store sensitive info is the keychain of your device.
There are a lot of libs on github that can help you in using it.
Pay attention that what you save inside the keychain will persist even after you remove the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this for saving credentials in the keychain. Just need to create an **Objective-c** file and import it in the **Bridging-header-file** of your project.

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KeychainUserPass : NSObject

+ (void)save:(NSString *)service data:(id)data;
+ (id)load:(NSString *)service;
+ (void)delete:(NSString *)service;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "KeychainUserPass.h"

@implementation KeychainUserPass

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)getKeychainQuery:(NSString *)service {

    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge id)kSecClass,
            service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrService,
            service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount,
            (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,
            nil];
}

+ (void)save:(NSString *)service data:(id)data {

    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
    [keychainQuery setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, NULL);
}

+ (id)load:(NSString *)service {

    id ret = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    CFDataRef keyData = NULL;

    if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&keyData) == noErr) {
        @try {
            ret = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)keyData];
        }
        @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"Unarchive of %@ failed: %@", service, e);
        }
        @finally {}
    }
    if (keyData) CFRelease(keyData);
    return ret;
}

+ (void)delete:(NSString *)service {

    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
}


@end
```

**Usage**:

Save: `KeychainUserPass.save("email", data: self.YOUR_TEXT_FIELD.text!)`

Load: `YOUR_STRING = KeychainUserPass.load("email") as? String`

Delete: `KeychainUserPass.delete("email")`